# Ant is downloading transitive dependencies from http instead of https

Tags: maven, ant, maven-central

I admit I'm not well versed in Ant.  Apparently, the first artifact does seem to recognize the use of https, but the transitive dependency does not.
I'm guessing that when maven central changed from http to https on January 15th something didn't change in the maven-ant-tasks-2.1.3.

```
20:16:26 ant-task-download:
20:16:27       [get] Getting: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-ant-tasks/2.1.3/maven-ant-tasks-2.1.3.jar
20:16:27       [get] To: /root/workspace/src/apache/hadoop/release_0.20.2+737/ivy/maven-ant-tasks-2.1.3.jar
20:16:27 
20:16:27 mvn-taskdef:
20:16:30 [artifact:dependencies] [INFO] artifact joda-time:joda-time: checking for updates from company-releases
20:16:30 [artifact:dependencies] [INFO] artifact joda-time:joda-time: checking for updates from company-snapshots
20:16:30 [artifact:dependencies] [INFO] artifact joda-time:joda-time: checking for updates from internal
20:16:30 [artifact:dependencies] [INFO] artifact joda-time:joda-time: checking for updates from central
20:16:30 [artifact:dependencies] [WARNING] repository metadata for: 'artifact joda-time:joda-time' could not be retrieved from repository: central due to an error: Error transferring file: Server returned HTTP response code: 501 for URL: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/joda-time/joda-time/maven-metadata.xml
20:16:30 [artifact:dependencies] [INFO] Repository 'central' will be blacklisted
20:16:30
```

The "https://repo1.maven.org/..." joda-time URL does exist.  Is there a fix this or a way to set the download to use the https URL?

Comment: Is there a good reason using Ant ? I would recommend to use Maven instead... ?

Comment: Yes there is.  And given a choice, I would use Gradle over Maven, or better yet I would use Bazel.

Comment: Ant itself is not the problem here; it's the maven-ant-tasks library. It has been retired for years. See the message on their main page: https://maven.apache.org/ant-tasks/index.html . As a simple workaround, you can just use the mvn command directly with Ant's `exec` task.

Comment: @user2569618 Be careful with Bazel. It is a niche product with nearly no market share.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. Finally I solved my problem by manually download all the dependency I need(write the dependency in a new pom and use newest version of maven to download), which can avoid ant driving download from deprecated http source.